# "Connection error. Please try logging in again" login into Last.FM from Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox

So, every time I try to login into Last.fm from the plugin in Rhythmbox I get the following error:

> "Connection error. Please try logging in again"

It seems normal since I haven't found a way to introduce my credentials. I cannot do it from "Edit/Plugins/Last.fm/Preferences" and if I right click on the link on the Library I only get the option to "Refresh Profile".

I've tried to enable/disable the plugin several times. I cannot find the way to enter the credentials either with `gconf-editor` or `dconf-editor`. I'm at a loss. Anyone knows the answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest upgrading to the latest version of Rhythmbox if you haven't already. The way I log in to last.fm is through a button in Rhythmbox that takes me to my browser in order to authenticate Rhythmbox and add it to the [connected applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cLF7.png) of last.fm, with no need to separately log in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm using 2.96-0ubuntu4.2 and when I click on "Log in" it does not open my browser.

Comment: OK. After you press "Log in" does it say "Waiting for authentication"? If it does I think it's a matter of your browser not opening. Check if you have a [default browser](http://i.imgur.com/lTHez.png) and have it open when clicking "Log in".
Also possible is [upgrading to 2.98](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/rhythmbox-298-released-install-it-in.html).
Last resort is waiting and hoping it works in 12.10.

Comment: It does not say "Waiting for authentication", the error pops right away... sorry. I've checked that Firefox is my default browser and that I have it open before clicking "Log in".

Comment: That's strange. 12.10 is coming out today, are you planning on upgrading? If so, I think your problems will be fixed by that. If you're doing a clean install then it'll be fine automatically. If you're upgrading from 12.04 then I suggest uninstalling Rhythmbox, upgrading, and then installing it in 12.10.

Comment: Even if you're not upgrading, have you tried re-installing Rhythmbox? To remove, use terminal: `sudo apt-get remove --purge rhythmbox`. This will remove the configuration files as well. You can install it again with terminal `sudo apt-get install rhythmbox`, or via the Software Center.

Comment: have you tried it yet? any luck?

Comment: Yes, I did but without any luck, sorry.